# how to parse individual JSON objects from one large JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to parse multiple JSON objects within one large JSON object. Right now it stores the whole JSON object as one and I need to parse them into their separate objects to be stored in a mongodb. Here is my code.

get request for orders

```
WooCommerce.get('orders', function(err, data, res){
console.log(res);
var parsedOrders = JSON.parse(res);
var step;
for(step = 0; step < parsedOrders.length; step++){
    var emagispaceOrders = new Orders({orders: step});
    emagispaceOrders.save();
}    
});
```

model used to store JSON object in mongoose schema

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;



var orderSchema = new Schema({
orders: {type: Object}
});

var Orders = mongoose.model('Orders', orderSchema);

module.exports = Orders;
```

it saves the an orders object but doesn't save the data within the JSON object. So basically to sum it up my mongodb is populated with specifically 8 empty objects that only contain whats shown below and not the actual data sent by the JSON objects.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd524224469604"), "orders" : 0, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd524224469606"), "orders" : 2, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd524224469605"), "orders" : 1, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd524224469607"), "orders" : 3, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd524224469608"), "orders" : 4, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd524224469609"), "orders" : 5, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd52422446960a"), "orders" : 6, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd52422446960b"), "orders" : 7, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd52422446960d"), "orders" : 9, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d93d05fdcd52422446960c"), "orders" : 8, "__v" : 0 }
```

when it should contain a full order submitted through woocommerce that contains order id, total, customer name, and so on and so forth.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit///////

mongoose schema

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;



var orderSchema = new Schema({
id: {type: Number},
parent_id: {type: Number},
status: {type: String},
number: {type: Number},
customer_id: {type: Number},
shipping_total: {type: String},
total: {type: String},
total_tax: {type: String}
});

var Orders = mongoose.model('Orders', orderSchema);

module.exports = Orders;
```

order JSON sample

```
{"id":6190,"parent_id":0,"status":"processing","order_key":"wc_order_58cc462aa2f9d","number":6190,"currency":"USD","version":"2.6.14","prices_include_tax":false,"date_created":"2017-03-17T20:25:00","date_modified":"2017-03-17T20:25:49","customer_id":1,"discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"814.50","shipping_tax":"72.04","cart_tax":"361.54","total":"5335.59","total_tax":"433.58","billing":{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","company":"Emagispace","address_1":"123 Billing Street","address_2":"Apt. #1","city":"Boulder","state":"CO","postcode":"80301","country":"US","email":"bt_buyer_us@paypal.com","phone":"312-123-4567"},"shipping":{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","company":"Emagispace","address_1":"123 Billing Street","address_2":"Apt. #1","city":"Boulder","state":"CO","postcode":"80301","country":"US"},"payment_method":"cheque","payment_method_title":"Our team will send you an invoice for products ordered.","transaction_id":"","customer_ip_address":"75.166.79.141","customer_user_agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/56.0.2924.87 Safari\/537.36","created_via":"checkout","customer_note":"","date_completed":"2017-03-17T20:25:49","date_paid":"","cart_hash":"bf2aeb9eba51a119baeb896cb778093d","line_items":[{"id":207,"name":"3' Emagiblock","sku":"2000003A","product_id":5924,"variation_id":0,"quantity":22,"tax_class":"","price":"96.88","subtotal":"2131.25","subtotal_tax":"188.51","total":"2131.25","total_tax":"188.51","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"188.5091","subtotal":"188.5091"}],"meta":[]},{"id":208,"name":"2' Emagiblock","sku":"2000002A","product_id":5920,"variation_id":0,"quantity":28,"tax_class":"","price":"52.49","subtotal":"1469.72","subtotal_tax":"130.00","total":"1469.72","total_tax":"130.00","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"129.9967","subtotal":"129.9967"}],"meta":[]},{"id":209,"name":"1' Emagiblock","sku":"2000001A","product_id":5916,"variation_id":0,"quantity":10,"tax_class":"","price":"33.66","subtotal":"336.60","subtotal_tax":"29.77","total":"336.60","total_tax":"29.77","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"29.7723","subtotal":"29.7723"}],"meta":[]},{"id":210,"name":"EmagiClip","sku":"4500001A","product_id":5984,"variation_id":0,"quantity":12,"tax_class":"","price":"12.50","subtotal":"149.94","subtotal_tax":"13.26","total":"149.94","total_tax":"13.26","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"13.2622","subtotal":"13.2622"}],"meta":[]}],"tax_lines":[{"id":212,"rate_code":"US-CO-CO TAX-1","rate_id":"1","label":"CO Tax","compound":false,"tax_total":"361.54","shipping_tax_total":"72.04"}],"shipping_lines":[{"id":211,"method_title":"Weight Based Shipping","method_id":"main","total":"814.50","total_tax":"72.04","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"72.042525"}]}],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.emagispace.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v1\/orders\/6190"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.emagispace.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v1\/orders"}],"customer":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.emagispace.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v1\/customers\/1"}]}}
```

this is one JSON response object. The response I'm recieving contains 35 of these and i need to parse those objects from the main/large JSON object containing the smaller order objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are not [valid Mongoose schema types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), which means you need to know in advance what shape your order objects will take, or Mongoose will just not save them.

**EDIT**

In response to your edit, I just noticed that you're not trying to save the correct object. You're doing

```
Orders({orders: step});
```

where `step` is an index, so you're effectively saving a number. What you want to do is

```
Orders({orders: parsedOrders[step]});
```

this will reference the correct order.

**EDIT 2**

Actually your schema is different in your original question and the edit. Either way bear in mind that to get to the order you need to reference it by `parsedOrders[step]`, where `step` is an index.

Comment: even when i specify each parameter for the mongoose schema as accordingly no information populates the model.

Comment: Please include your code for the schema and a sample order object